# How to Paginate this PHP MySQL data table?

Tags: php

I am new in PHP. And my code is given below. I want to paginate my data tables. So how to modify? I have already tried some tutorials. But as a beginner I can't solve the problem.

```
<?php
  } else {
    $result = executeQuery("SELECT t.*,s.subname
                              FROM test AS t,
                                   subject AS s 
                              WHERE s.subid=t.subid
                                AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP<t.testto
                                AND t.totalquestions=(SELECT count(*)
                                                        FROM question
                                                        WHERE testid=t.testid)
                                AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT stdid,testid
                                                 FROM studenttest
                                                 WHERE testid=t.testid
                                                   AND stdid=" . $_SESSION['stdid'].");");


    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
      echo"<h3 style=\"color:#0000cc;text-align:center;\">There are no results!</h3>";
    } else {

?>
```

I am taking the output from :

```
<tr>
  <th>Exam name</th>
  <th>Details</th>
  <th>Subject</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  <th>Questions</th>
  <th>Start</th>
</tr>
```

And for table data I am using:

```
<?php
  while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i = $i + 1;
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
      echo "<tr class=\"alt\">";
    } else {
      echo "<tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['testname'], ENT_QUOTES) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['testdesc'], ENT_QUOTES) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['subname'], ENT_QUOTES)
                    . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['duration'], ENT_QUOTES) . "</td><td>" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['totalquestions'], ENT_QUOTES) . "</td>"
                    . "<td class=\"tddata\"><a title=\"Click Here\" href=\"stdtest.php?testcode=" . htmlspecialchars_decode($r['testname'], ENT_QUOTES) . "\"><img src=\"images/starttest.png\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" alt=\"Start Test\" /></a></td></tr>";
  }
?>
</table>

<?php
    }
    closedb();
  }
}
?>
```

Now what can I do ? I am very new here and this is my first post here. Thanks.

Comment: As a beginner, you shouldn't code blindly in thinking your code will work without errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()` or whatever you're using for `executeQuery()`. Plus, make sure you are indeed connecting with `mysql_` and not some other MySQL API.

Comment: *"I am new in PHP"* - and you've already learned how to do fancy selects like that?

Comment: 1). You need to use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your `SELECT` query. 2). Calculate number of pages based on how many results you want to show on one page and how many total rows returned from query. 3). Create links on page to navigate through the pages. Here is an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

Comment: This question is too broad in its current format. You show no attempt at pagination, which gives the impression you want us to do your work. Take some time to review similar questions here on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+mysql+pagination - and then show your effort.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That fancy select query looks like someone one gave it to them, and they wouldn't know what it does, or how to modify it.

Comment: @Sean I can remember putting water on my face first, before jumping into the deep end. If only I could swim in the ocean before I can flyfish in a stream without the risk of drowning from being pulled in by a Chinook  ;-)

Comment: OP testing the waters, as it were.

Comment: That query looks kinda like how I see people write SQL queries for *SQL Server* rather than MySQL... it's possible the OP knows their way around .NET and SQL Server but not PHP ... unlikely, but possible I suppose. The brace indentation is different to how Visual Studio does it so doubly unlikely.

Comment: @Sean A quick search on Google using part of their code in their select, yielded https://github.com/havesolutions/examination/blob/master/stdtest.php and http://ideone.com/jHXZpo and http://ideone.com/fork/38ylT etc. So that tells me they've either been given code as you said, or they've found code and are asking us to hash something together for them. I wouldn't touch this question with a 10 foot fishing pole. I'll save it for the Chinook ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple and inline with what you know, I would simply have a next button which will add a query to your current page. By default, show the first 25 results. Then have a button that will add a page parameter as a query (e.g. `<a href="myScript.php?page=2">Next</a>`).

In your logic, check for this query `$_GET["page"]`, and then get the results based on what page the user is on. I'm assuming you are able to do this based on what you have already written.

Then working from that, you could add a previous button and individual page number buttons.